# 'Currency' is only available in iOS 16 or newer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After updating Xcode to 14 suddenly I'm unable to build our app, getting the error

```
'Currency' is only available in iOS 16 or newer
```

but we've been using `Currency` already as our backend model:

```
struct Currency: Equatable {
    let code: String
    let symbol: String
    let localizedString: String
}
```

We getting the error when using `Currency` here:

```
extension Locale {
    static let availableCurrencies: [Currency] = Currency.availableCurrencies
}
```

Comment: You can alter the name of the `model` or you can write it as `AppName.Currency`, then it will know which `struct` you mean.

Comment: Well `availableCurrencies` is not a property of your custom structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the error is newly displaying in xcode 14 is, that Apple added their own `struct Currency` to `Foundation` which is only available in iOS 16. In some places it cannot determine which `Currency` you mean.

In our soulution we just renamed our `struct Currency` to `struct CurrenyModel` to resolve the naming conflict. You can use <kbd>F2</kbd> (or Right Click -> Refactor -> Rename) when the name is selected to rename all references at once.